# Change an if statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement

jQuery is so hard to understand for me. Everytime I have to use it I end up reading docs for hours to achieve nothing. I'm using this code (live-editing is available).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKFBy

It filters records in real time while tyiping in an input text. The problem is that I don't want its search method. Let me explain.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="in"><span>google.com</span></li>
  <li class="in"><span>gmail.com</span></li>
  <li class="in"><span>samsung.com</span></li>
  <li class="in"><span>amazon.de</span></li>
  <li class="in"><span>apple.de</span></li>
</ul>
```

When I type "G" or "g" (it's case insensitive) amazon.de and apple.de disappear because they don't contain any "G" meanwhile google.com gmail.com and samsung.com remain visible. This is the problem. I don't want to keep samsun**g**.com just because at some point it has a "g". I want to return only elements where span **begins** with a certain string. In pratical terms this is what I'm trying to reproduce.

I type "G":

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="in"><span>google.com</span></li>
  <li class="in"><span>gmail.com</span></li>
  <li class="hiding out hidden"><span>samsung.com</span></li>
  <li class="hiding out hidden"><span>amazon.de</span></li>
  <li class="hiding out hidden"><span>apple.de</span></li>
</ul>
```

I keep typing "Go":

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="in"><span>google.com</span></li>
  <li class="hiding out hidden"><span>gmail.com</span></li>
  <li class="hiding out hidden"><span>samsung.com</span></li>
  <li class="hiding out hidden"><span>amazon.de</span></li>
  <li class="hiding out hidden"><span>apple.de</span></li>
</ul>
```

I know the syntax that I should use:

```
indexOf(searchTerm)
```

Or:

```
[span^="'+searchTerm+'"]
```

Or:

```
str.match(/^searchTerm/)
```

But I can't manage to edit the current if statements. Everytime I break the script.

Comment: Side-note: You have nested your `:containsi` jQuery extension inside a `keyup` handler! Best you reformat you code and look at the nesting with some urgency :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. Why are you saying this? Do you mean that it could be a problem for performances?

Comment: You should not needlessly run code over and over when it only needs to be initialised once. I was concerned you may have other similar issues. Best to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `:startswith` custom selector (or `:startswithi` if you need to be specific) and check for position 0 on the `indexOf` match:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/z148kzeo/

```
    //extends :contains to be case insensitive
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        'startswith': function (elem, i, match, array) {
            return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
                .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) == 0;
        }
    });
```

Please note you are adding your custom selector inside a `keyup` handler event (on every keyup). I moved it to the start.

Comment: I got it. You are totally right. Keyup event was pointless. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `indexOf` function checks the the found index is *greater than* or equal to 0. Set it to equal 0 to check the beginning of the string:

```
{
return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
    .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) == 0;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/japcB

Comment: I can't belive how I missed that part... thank you a ton

Answer (score 0):

I already see couple answers here. Let me throw in another option as well.. take the value from your search text and create a regular expression pattern and look for that pattern in the list elements. I am not an expert but right off the back this is what I thought of immediately. Hope this helps someone :)